# Good one-to-many relation practice in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am developing the structure of the MySQL database and I've faced a small decisional problem about its structure.

I have 2 tables:

1. All messages published on the site.
2. All comments published on the site.

Every message can have more than one comment associated to it.
What is a better way to make connection between a message and comments related to it?

1. Have a field for comments that contains id of the related message.
2. Have a field for messages that contains an array of ids of related comments in json format.

I think that usually the first method is used and then MySQL query is used to find comments that have message_id of corresponding message. But how efficient will it be when there are hundreds of thousands of comments?

Will in this case decoding json string and accessing comments by exact unique id be more efficient and fast?

I am using python for back-end if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is the way to go. So you'll have:

comment_id | message_id | comment_text | timestamp etc.

For your MySQL table you can specify to build the index over the first two columns for good performance.
10Mio Comments should work OK, but you could test this in advance with a test scenario yourself.

If you want to plan for more, then after about 100,000 comments you can do the following:

- determine how many comments there are on average per message
- determine how many messages would be required for about 5mio comments
- let's say it takes 50,000 messages for 5mio comments
- add comment_table1 [..] comment_table9 to your database
- switch within python: if message_id > 50,000 -> then look at comment_table2 etc.
- Of course, you'll have to save the comments accordingly

This should be performant for a large number of entries.

You can adapt the numbers to your individual hosting (performance) environment...

Comment: Thank you. This is a good approach. Is that the way, the giants like Facebook, Twitter, ... organize the huge volumes of data? Or do there exist even better ways than dividing information into multiple tables?

Comment: The "giants" use different techniques. They use NoSQL databases or database clusters, for example. Facebook published quite a lot of information about their technology...

Answer (score 0):

Option one is the best approach. You'll want an index on the `message_id` column in the comments table. This allows MySQL to quickly and efficiently pull out all the comments for a particular message, even when there are hundreds of thousands of comments.